# Securing key into Android app from decompilation and developers

Tags: java, android, security, android-ndk, obfuscation

I am working on a project which requires the secret key to be hidden somewhere in the Android app, so that it can't be taken out even after decompilation.
The requirement even states that the key should not be visible to the developer, that means it should be embedded into some pre-compiled library.
I have tried the following things:

1. Making Jar and obfuscating the jar, Which becomes unusable after that. And its useless method to work with Strings (it doesn't encrypt Strings).
2. Making C library and using that library(NDK). The strings can be easily read using linux commands. Example: '$ strings '.

I am trying to find out other ways by which this can be done.
Please help me with this. If you have any idea, please share. I would be more than obliged.

Thanks.

Comment: By definition, the requirement is impossible. If the app can be executed and have access to the secret key, then anyone else can get the secret key. For example, they could run the app and use a debugger. Or, they could go through the same steps the app does to decode the secret key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hard problem.  You're fighting a battle against reverse engineering your application.  There are tools that are build for this, notably [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) and [Arxan](https://www.arxan.com/what-we-do/how-we-protect-apps/).  Arxan is really, really clever, but it will cost a lot more than a solution like DexGuard.

Comment: Thanks. For the suggestion. I am looking into Arxan from past few days and it might help me.

Comment: Hello @lang_android, do you have any idea related to root detection in android with Arxan?

Answer (score 2):

Anything that your app can do, can also be reverse engineered by a determined capable hacker, so don't expect some magic way to make this key perpetually secured.

If your goal is to supply an SDK that will be licensed to different developers, then the easy approach is to allocate a unique key for each developer, and let them take care of hiding it from hackers.

On the other hand, if I read your requirement literally, it is enough that the key string will not appear in plain text in the APK. The easy solution is to encode it. You can do something as easy as base64 encoding of the key, or as tricky as providing a C function that will calculate this key on the fly (so no traces of the key will appear in the output of `strings`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use one of the encoding for the key, isn't possible that the debugger will be capable of taking out and showing the key in clear text.

Comment: No, debugger *the program* will not do that, but debugger *the human* can do it relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

For aar and jar protection against decompilation you can use [Quixxi](https://quixxisecurity.com/docs/platforms/android/). Of course the effort is about raising the overall protection as much as possible, impossible is nothing. But this solution joins the best of both the points you made. What happens is the following conversion:

input: unprotected jar file

[image: input jar file]

output: java file calling the native layer

[image: output jar file]

You [or the developer that will need to manage the app containing your library] can later integrate it as described in the same link. Moreover the entire app can be protected with the same tool if other parts of it will need to be secured